# display form.valid when user can't valid [angular]

Tags: forms, angular, validation

So. I follow the tutorial on build in validator and form validation on the official doc ->

One of the thing that chock me is that you can't know why you can't submit your form when something is wrong.

Take the plunker exemple they give in the [doc](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/form-validation.html):  plunker -> https://plnkr.co/edit/TJUZlkKOv22PzPB7gHEK?p=preview

You can NOT click on submit, your mouse turn into a stop signal which is fine and normal.

But you have to check all over your form to find what you missed.
I hope there would be a way to put a tooltip to show which field was required/falsy to at least explain to the user "something is wrong in what you did, check this particular field (which is paint in red but you look too d*** to understand)'.

Do you have any clue about how to access to `form.valid` and get some minimal explenation about why the form in not valid.

Comment: I don't understand, that plunker does show error messages, for example if you erase the name of the hero, it shows it's required. You can manage these error messages e.g if form is `touched`, `dirty`, `pristine`.

Answer (score 1):

you can go for reactive form as in plunker 3 and have some expression like below to display user message, based on  the validity condition.

```
<span *ngIf="!form.get('userData.email').valid && signUpForm.get('userData.email').touched" class="help-block">
            Please enter a valid Email!
</span>
```

Please let me know if your requirement is different.

Comment: `!valid can be just invalid` :)

Comment: I have some trouble understanding which is what, userData in particular. and not sure about signUpForm

Comment: signUpForm is formGroup, userData is formGroupName and email is formControlName.... This is the way you define reactive form.